# Querydsl: innerJoin and JPASubQuery

Tags: jakarta-ee, querydsl

How can I implement this SQL query with Querydsl?

```
SELECT UserProfile.* FROM UserAccount_has_Workgroup 
INNER JOIN UserAccount ON UserAccount_has_Workgroup.userAccountID=UserAccount.userAccountID 
INNER JOIN UserProfile ON UserAccount.userAccountID = UserProfile.userAccountID
WHERE UserAccount_has_Workgroup.UserAccountID NOT IN
    (SELECT UserAccountID FROM UserAccount_has_Workgroup WHERE workgroupID = 2)
AND UserAccount.roleId <> 2;
```

I've try with this one but it returns an empty result:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager); 

query = query.from(userAccountHasWorkgroup)
     .innerJoin(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId, userAccount)
     .innerJoin(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.userProfile, qUserProfile)
    .where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId
       .notIn(new JPASubQuery().from(userAccountHasWorkgroup)
                .where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.workgroup.id.eq(workgroupId))
                .list(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId))
            )
   .where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.role.name.ne(role.getRoleString()))
        ;

  List<UserProfile>  results = query.list(userProfile);
```

Comment: The result of the construction of the query is: "select userAccountHasWorkgroup
from UserAccountHasWorkgroup userAccountHasWorkgroup
  inner join userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId as userAccount
  inner join userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.userProfile as userProfile
where userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId not in (select userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId
from UserAccountHasWorkgroup userAccountHasWorkgroup
where userAccountHasWorkgroup.workgroup.id = ?1) and userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.role.name <> ?2"

Comment: I think the error is in the translation of the query: "select userAccountHasWorkgroup" should be "select userProfile"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like WHERE expressions are completely different in you examples:

```
AND UserAccount.roleId <> 2;
```

vs

```
 where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.role.name.ne(role.getRoleString()))
```

Also I think you shoouldn't use two WHERE expressions in a row, but should

```
.where(expr1.and(expr2))
```

like in native SQL

Comment: You're right, I have omitted a table for simplicity. where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.role.roleId.ne(roleId). That is the same

Comment: what about unchaining where expressions?

Comment: Could you kindly provide me an example?

Comment: in your case t will be
.where(
 userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId .notIn(new JPASubQuery().from(userAccountHasWorkgroup).where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.workgroup.id.eq(workgroupId)).list(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId)),
    userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.role.name.ne(role.getRoleString())
    )

Comment: in your case t will be

`.where(
 userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId 
  .notIn(new JPASubQuery().from(userAccountHasWorkgroup)
  .where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.workgroup.id.eq(workgroupId))
  .list(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId)),
    userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId.role.name.ne(role.getRoleString())
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Trying this query, apparently the result is the one I expected::

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager); 

query = query.from(userAccount)     
        .innerJoin(userAccount.userProfile, userProfile)
        .where(userAccount.notIn(new JPASubQuery()
            .from(userAccountHasWorkgroup).where(userAccountHasWorkgroup.workgroup.id.eq(workgroupId))
            .list(userAccountHasWorkgroup.userAccountByUserAccountId)))
        .where(userAccount.role.name.ne(role.getRoleString()));
```

Passing from `UserAccount` table (`UserAccount` is in `N<-->N` relationship with `UserAccountHasWorkgroup`)